# How i make export my Flex project for IOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

How i make export my Flex project for IOS.
I am using Flash Builder 4.5 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yesterday's topic on [flexcoders](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/162698) groups

1) get an ios device

2) http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action look around, for a .p12 developer certificate, and a provisioning file

3) create an as mobile project, write/import code

4) when releasing as mobile project, fill ios options with stuff from step 2. (if you have prerelease flash builder, you can also do a flex mobile project)

5) test on device

6) make the fat people smile :)

Thanks to [Gábor Csomák](http://profiles.yahoo.com/csomakgabor) ;

Comment: I thought Flash Builder 4.5 didn't support iOS in the Flex Mobile Project. I remember reading that it only supported iOS features in the Actionscript Mobile Project. This is simply an IDE issue however. You can still build the project from the command line using the ADT compiler (I do this with an automated ANT build process). Please correct me if this has changed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

last day when i start my PC adobe update as me to update two software
1. Adobe AIR for IOS
2. Flash Builder 4.5.1.

When i complete the update i found that Adobe provide the support for the IOS built in for Flex project.

```
http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/05/three-platforms-one-application-mobiletrader-for-ios-android-and-playbook-source-code-available/
```

or follow this link that i am found after some long search

```
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html
```

Enjoy.